# Where are the in and out members of java.lang.System initialized?

Tags: java, io, jvm, printstream

I have two questions related to the `System` class of java.

First, where are in (input) and out (output) objects initialized? As these objects are declared as static and not initialized in the `System` class, and `System` class does not have a constructor.

The second question is, in (input) object is declared as input stream that is why it reads byte data and the out object is also `outputStream` then why it is able to write all type of primitive data. Stream is  used to read/write bytes data. Do not say it calls the `toString` method.

Comment: See http://tutorialscrux.com/java/systemoutprintln/system-out-println-java-explained/

Answer (score 3):

The `System` class members `in`, `out`, and `err` are initialized in the private function `initializeSystemClass()`. This function is invoked by the JVM initialization procedures.

The member [`out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is *not* only an `OutputStream`. It is a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), and has an extended API. All of the [`print()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-int-) methods that accept arguments of primitive type use the corresponding [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-) methods to create a `String` object representing the value. These strings are then funneled through an [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) instance that encodes text into bytes using a specific character encoding. The resulting bytes are written to the appropriate file descriptor.